# How to solve 'TemplateDoesNotExist' error in Django 4.2 while running the server?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:5555/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\soumy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during:  geekshows.views.home
Python Executable:  C:\Users\soumy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.3
Python Path:    
['F:\\Django\\geekshows',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python311\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\soumy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 22 May 2023 13:56:05 +0000

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: F:\Django\geekshows\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\soumy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\soumy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: F:\Django\geekshows\course\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: F:\Django\geekshows\fees\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
```

When I am running server this error is comming. I am using Django 4.2 so how to over come.

---

Folder Structure:

F:\Django\geekshows
[course folder and fees folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmAOE.png)

[fees and geekshows folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJpDi.png)

**1. course\templates\course\course1.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Hello {{nm}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. course\templates\course\course2.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Python</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**3. course\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
# from course.views import learn_django
# from fees.views import fees_django
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('learndj/', views.learn_django),
    path('learnpy/', views.learn_python)
]
```

**4. course\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
# Create your views here.

def learn_django(request):
    return render(request, 'course/course1.html', {'nm':'Django'})

def learn_python(request):
    return render(request, 'course/course2.html')
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the listed files really exist?

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have a view `home` that renders `home.html` but `home.html` cant be found

```
Raised during:  geekshows.views.home
...
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: F:\Django\geekshows\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
```

please note that you seem to have a non standard structure of your app as a view file should be inside an app (like `.../geekshows/main/views.py`) but yours seems to be in the project root folder geekshows.

standard structure:

```
geekshows/                      # project root
   main/                        # app main (or another name)
      templates/
          main/
             home.html
      models.py
      views.py
      ...
   course/                      # app course
   fees/                        # app fees
   geekshows/                   # folder with same name as project -> django entry point for requests
      urls.py
      wsgi.py
      settings.py
   manage.py
```

please post the view and show the folder structure where you placed home.html to further answer your question

Answer (score 0):

This is a answer to Razenstein

**5. geekshows\templates\home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Home {{name}}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**6. geekshows\settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for geekshows project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR =  BASE_DIR / "templates"


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0q$2kj0_mvxvfz!w((9#-qp+_ceqkdcl+g9^_zq^c$7$ew1h&y'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'course',
    'fees',
    'result',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'geekshows.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'geekshows.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**7. geekshows\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('cor/', include('course.urls')),
    path('fe/', include('fees.urls')),
    path('', views.home),
    
]
```

**8. geekshows\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name':'Page'})
```